# Does Pokemon Battle Revolution support CPU vs CPU battles?

Tags: nintendo-wii, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum, pokemon-battle-revolution

Pokemon Battle Revolution for Wii has battles where you fight the CPU. I was wondering, before I manage to get a copy, is there CPU vs CPU? And is that rental only or can you create two passes with imported Pokemons from DPPt and make them fight eachother? I cannot find any information on this on the internet and I do not know any people that have the game that I can ask.

Does Pokemon Battle Revolution feature CPU vs CPU battles, where obviously the player does pick the teams beforehand?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.